# Nav bar stick under other nav bar on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, navigation

I would like to ask how can I have a nav bar sticked under other nav bar witch is positioned fixed?

Actually I want the menu-bottom navigation witch is at the bottom of the page to stuck under the menu-top navigation when I srcoll down

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    var topDist = $("").position();
    if (scroll > topDist.top) {
        $('.menu').css({"position":"absolute","bottom":"0"});
    } else {
        $('.menu').css({"position":"static","top":"80"});
    }
});
```

[Here is what I have done](http://jsfiddle.net/ntinos212000/vx7x2vdL/)

I have seen many jquery plugins but not found them useful - I am not good in scripting so need your help thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want the scroll to stop once the bottom nav bar scrolls under the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including the `height` of the menus and changing also to position fixed the bottom nav:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var mtHeight = $('.menu-top').height(),
        mbHeight = $('.menu-bottom').height(),
        scroll = $(this).scrollTop() + mtHeight + mbHeight,
        topDist = $(".page.two").position();
    if (scroll > topDist.top) {
        $('.menu-bottom').css({"position":"fixed","top":mtHeight});
    } else {
        $('.menu-bottom').css({"position":"absolute","top":"auto"});
    }
});
```

Check this [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vx7x2vdL/1/)